# Is there a way to set temporary flags on Excel workbook objects?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, interop

I have a C# helper class (`ExcelMacroHelper`) that assists with injecting VBA macro code into open Excel workbooks and running the resulting macros.  I just realized that the following steps would break my code:

1. C# application injects macro code into the active workbook, which causes the `ExcelMacroHelper` to mark its state as ready to run macros
2. The user switches to a different workbook in Excel.
3. The C# application attempts to run a macro.  The `ExcelMacroHelper` will think it is ready to run macros, but the VBA code was injected into a different workbook so the call will fail.

To fix this, I think I need some way of setting a temporary property on the `Workbook` object indicating that my macro code has been injected into it, or at least a way of maintaining a list of `Workbook`s that have been handled.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using custom document properties.  Something like this:

```
private bool needToInjectMacroCode() {
    // Get custom document property with name tagPropertyName

    object properties, property, propertyValue;

    properties = excel.ActiveWorkbook.GetType().InvokeMember(
        "CustomDocumentProperties",
        BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
        null, excel.ActiveWorkbook, null);

    try {
        property = properties.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Item",
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
            null, properties, new object[] { tagPropertyName });
    } catch (TargetInvocationException) {
        return true;
    }

    propertyValue = property.GetType().InvokeMember(
        "Value",
        BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
        null, property, null);

    return (tagString != (propertyValue as string));
}

// ...

private void setMacroCodeInjected() {
    // Set custom property with name tagPropertyName to value tagString

    object properties = excel.ActiveWorkbook.GetType().InvokeMember(
        "CustomDocumentProperties",
        BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
        null, excel.ActiveWorkbook, null);

    try {
        properties.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Add",
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, properties, new object[] {
                tagPropertyName, false,
                Office.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString,
                tagString
            });
    } catch (TargetInvocationException) {
        object property = properties.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Item",
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
            null, properties, new object[] { tagPropertyName });

        property.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Value",
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
            null, property, new object[] { tagString });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Names to hold values (as well as range references etc)

In pseudo code

```
if not (name already exists) then
    Set nm = workbook.Names.add("Injected")
    nm.Value = False
    nm.Visable = False
end if

if nm.value = False
    //Inject Code
    nm.value = true
endif
```

Note: simplest way to test if name exists is to try to access it and handle the error if it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.tag%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property of the [Workbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook_properties%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

When you inject the code, you could do something like this:

```
public class ExcelMacroHelper
{
   public static void Inject(Workbook workbook)
   {
       if ((workbook.Tag as String != "Injected"))
       {
          //Inject the code

           workbook.Tag = "Injected";
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I would want, except `Workbook` objects don't have a `Tag` property for me (using Office 2007).

Comment: @jnylen - that's odd... I just spun up an Office 2007 Workbook project (Visual Studio 2008) and it has a tag property.

Comment: I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library and namespace.  It seems likely that you're using the VSTO Excel library instead.